# How to capture network calls in node js/Java?

Tags: java, node.js, http, httprequest, firebug

In firebug addon for firefox there is a tab named 'Net' which captures all the network calls made when we hit an URL from the browser

I can request the URL from code but i am finding ways to capture the network calls being made, get the request parameters passed in the network call

Can this be done using NodeJS/Java?

[image]

Question Update: Whether the same is possible in Java?

Comment: I am assuming you are looking at this for debugging, not production. Have you seen: (iron-node)[https://github.com/s-a/iron-node]? There is another tool very similar but the name is not popping into mind right now.

Comment: Do you want to capture "all the network calls to your webserver?" or "all the network calls from your browser?".
If you want "all the network calls to your webserver", you can achieve this using a very simple middleware (if you are using express framework)

Comment: To make it clear, For ex, from firefox (open firebug addon) Hit http://www.google.com, In the "Net" Panel of firebug addon, you can see several calls being made. One of them being a call to plus.google.com, If you expand the call, u can see req-headers,  response-headers. Manually i can get the request-header's attribute and value. My question here is,From nodejs, I can make a request to http://www.google.com but is it possible to capture the request-header, params-passed or any other attributes from the network call (In our example - I need to get req-headers of plus.google.com) from js code

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the [request](https://github.com/request/request) module along with the [request-debug](https://github.com/request/request-debug) module:

```
var request = require('request')
var debug = require('request-debug')
debug(request)

request('http://google.com')
```

Here is what I'm seeing in my console after executing the above code:

```
{ request: 
   { debugId: 1,
     uri: 'http://google.com/',
     method: 'GET',
     headers: { host: 'google.com' } } }
{ redirect: 
   { debugId: 1,
     statusCode: 302,
     headers: 
      { 'cache-control': 'private',
        'content-type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
        location: 'http://www.google.bg/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=AgEqVt-BLqOz8we1v5P4Cw',
        'content-length': '258',
        date: 'Fri, 23 Oct 2015 09:42:26 GMT',
        server: 'GFE/2.0',
        connection: 'close' },
     uri: 'http://www.google.bg/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=AgEqVt-BLqOz8we1v5P4Cw' } }
{ request: 
   { debugId: 1,
     uri: 'http://www.google.bg/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=AgEqVt-BLqOz8we1v5P4Cw',
     method: 'GET',
     headers: { referer: 'http://google.com/', host: 'www.google.bg' } } }
{ response: 
   { debugId: 1,
     headers: 
      { date: 'Fri, 23 Oct 2015 09:42:26 GMT',
        expires: '-1',
        'cache-control': 'private, max-age=0',
        'content-type': 'text/html; charset=windows-1251',
        p3p: 'CP="This is not a P3P policy! See http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151657 for more info."',
        server: 'gws',
        'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block',
        'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
        'set-cookie': [Object],
        'accept-ranges': 'none',
        vary: 'Accept-Encoding',
        connection: 'close' },
     statusCode: 200 } }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. However i need to capture all the network calls that been made when we hit http://www.google.com (Please refer the snapshot attached in the question part). Is there any way to capture in nodejs

Comment: NodeJS is not a browser. After a browser makes the initial request to get the HTML document, it parses it and makes the additional requests like loading images and so on.

Comment: ya I agree on your point. I am just searching for any node library to capture all the calls like the firebug addon does.

Answer (score 1):

i have created this example that use http.IncomingMessage object for reading the three interesting properties (request.method,request.url and request.headers)

```
 //Lets require/import the HTTP module
var http = require('http');
//Lets define a port we want to listen to
const PORT=8080; 
//We need a function which handles requests and console request info
function handleRequest(request, response){
    console.log("===================");
    console.log("request.url : "+request.url);
    console.log("===================");
    console.log("request.method : "+request.method);  
    console.log("===================");  
    console.log("request.headers : "+JSON.stringify(request.headers));  
    console.log("===================");
    console.log("request.httpVersion : "+request.httpVersion);  
    console.log("===================");
    response.end();
}
//Create a server
var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);
//Lets start our server
server.listen(PORT, function(){
    //Callback triggered when server is successfully listening. Hurray!
    console.log("Server listening on: http://localhost:%s", PORT);
});
```

Comment: I downvoted your answer, because essentially you are not answering the question. Providing links to the official documentation is nowhere near helpful + you are not explaining how exactly the http and https modules allows you to capture network calls?

Comment: because I am trying to create an example that demonstrates how to capture http network call and  reading  the contains interesting properties using http module

Comment: OK, I removed my downvote, just for the effort. Though I think the question is about how to capture client calls, not server ones.

Answer (score 1):

There is a basic HTTP console proxy server solution.
Run inetcpl.cpl and set proxy to localhost:8080, then run this proxy server on a console:

```
    var httpProxy = require("http-proxy");
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");
var net = require('net');
var strftime = require('strftime');

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var urlObj = url.parse(req.url);
  let nw = {
            start: strftime('%F %T.%L'),
            end:0,
            url: req.url,
            host: urlObj.protocol + "//" + urlObj.host,
            request:{
                     content:[],
                     headers:[]
                     },
            response:{
                     content:[],
                     headers:[]
                     }
            };
  console.log("HTTP: ", nw.host );
      
  var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({});
  
  proxy.on("error", function (err, req, res) {
    console.log("proxy error", err);
    res.end();
  });

  proxy.web(req, res, { target: nw.host,
                        selfHandleResponse : true } );

  req.on('data', (chunk) => {
    ( nw.request.content ).push(chunk);
  }).on('end', () => {
    nw.request.content = Buffer.concat( nw.request.content ).toString(); 
    return;
  });
  
  proxy.on('proxyRes', function (proxyRes, req, res) {
      nw.response.headers = proxyRes.headers;
      proxyRes.on('data', function (chunk) {
          ( nw.response.content ).push(chunk);
      }).on('end', function () {
          nw.response.content = Buffer.concat( nw.response.content ).toString();
          //res.end( nw.response.content );
          res.end();
      });
  });
  
  res.on("finish", () => {
    nw.request.headers = req.headers;
    nw.end= strftime('%F %T.%L');
    console.log( nw );
    return;
  });
  
}).listen(8080);
```

The result is looks like this:

```
HTTP:  http://redirector.gvt1.com
{
  start: '2020-09-19 11:31:54.020',
  end: '2020-09-19 11:31:54.061',
  url: 'http://redirector.gvt1.com/edgedl/release2/chrome_component/AIKCnnAtp9v2eS4vn_zJZyA_2135/bbfjzj0vPWuXZOhpCzAp9Q',
  host: 'http://redirector.gvt1.com',
  request: {
    content: '',
    headers: {
      'proxy-connection': 'Keep-Alive',
      accept: '*/*',
      'accept-encoding': 'identity',
      range: 'bytes=0-249',
      'user-agent': 'Microsoft BITS/7.8',
      host: 'redirector.gvt1.com'
    }
  },
  response: {
    content: '&lt;HTML>&lt;HEAD>&lt;meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">\n' +
      '&lt;TITLE>302 Moved&lt;/TITLE>&lt;/HEAD>&lt;BODY>\n' +
      '&lt;H1>302 Moved&lt;/H1>\n' +
      'The document has moved\n' +
      '&lt;A HREF="http://r5---sn-po8puxa-c0qs.gvt1.com/edgedl/release2/chrome_component/AIKCnnAtp9v2eS4vn_zJZyA_2135/bbfjzj0vPWuXZOhpCzAp9Q?cms_redirect=yes&amp;mh=9R&amp;mip=212.24.176.76&amp;mm=28&amp;mn=sn-po8puxa-c0qs&amp;ms=nvh&amp;mt=1600507629&amp;mv=u&amp;mvi=5&amp;pl=19&amp;shardbypass=yes">here&lt;/A>.\r\n' +
      '&lt;/BODY>&lt;/HTML>\r\n',
    headers: {
      date: 'Sat, 19 Sep 2020 09:31:54 GMT',
      pragma: 'no-cache',
      expires: 'Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT',
      'cache-control': 'no-cache, must-revalidate',
      location: 'http://r5---sn-po8puxa-c0qs.gvt1.com/edgedl/release2/chrome_component/AIKCnnAtp9v2eS4vn_zJZyA_2135/bbfjzj0vPWuXZOhpCzAp9Q?cms_redirect=yes&mh=9R&mip=212.24.176.76&mm=28&mn=sn-po8puxa-c0qs&ms=nvh&mt=1600507629&mv=u&mvi=5&pl=19&shardbypass=yes',
      'content-type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
      server: 'ClientMapServer',
      'content-length': '478',
      'x-xss-protection': '0',
      'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
      connection: 'close'
    }
  }
}
```

This shows very basic informations: host, url, start and end time, request and response header and content.

Answer (score 0):

In node we have `morgan`  to view the logs. Although it may not completely serve what you have asked for. But it is used to view all the calls made through node.